# Excel 'Workbook Open' Code not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an excel(xlsm) file with Vba Code under 'Workbook Open' event. This file is protected with a password. When I open the file, it asks for password, I give the password, Workbook opens, but 'Workbook Open' code does not work. Any solution?

Comment: Check your Excel macro security settings. Does a yellow bar appear at the top saying "Enable content" after you've opened the file?

Comment: Does the Workbook Open code run successfully when the file is not password-protected?

Comment: @FlexYourData The macro security settings checked, the macros have been enabled in the trust center without any prompt. ActiveX settings also enabled without restrictions. But when the file opens after giving password, the following message appears. 'Security Alert - The file contains encrypted macros that have been disabled because there is no antivirus software installed that can scan them. To run these macros, remove the encryption or permission restrictions of the file.' I do not know how to deal with this security alert.

Comment: @RegEdit Yes, Workbook Open code runs successfully when it is not password protected. I have reinstalled Office[2007] fearing corruption but the problem remains. I have also created a copy of the above file by taking separate copies of each sheet in it but still the problem remains. Please give any suggestions to solve this.

Comment: I have been browsing for solutions and stumbled upon this link  http://www.datasafexl.com/Webhelp/Knowledgebase/KB1015_-_Cannot_run_macros_in_Microsoft_Excel_2007.htm which states a Workaround but the corresponding link is dead. Any one know what this workaround is?

Comment: Can you share some code samples?

Comment: @Makubx you should edit your question to add the new information, that you are seeing a security alert, as this changes everything and anyone coming along trying to help needs to know that up front--they may not see it buried in a comment ("This file contains encrypted macros that have been disabled because there is no anti-virus software installed that can scan them. To run these macros, remove the encryption or permission restrictions on the file")

Answer (score 0):

*(Answer added before having the updated info to say there was a security alert. Retaining answer anyway in case it is useful.)*

Since this may be a bug that was fixed after Office 2007 was released, you should ensure you have installed the latest Office 2007 service pack.

The last service pack for Office 2007 was [Service Pack 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2007#Service_packs). This is a cumulative service pack, so you do not need to separately install earlier service packs. Information and download links for SP3 are available [here from  Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2526086/description-of-the-2007-office-suite-sp3-and-of-office-language-pack-2).